# Reflectance and Wavelength

Tags: optics

I want to create a graph of reflectance versus wavelength (reflectance spectrum- for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Bragg_reflector#mediaviewer/File:DBRREFL.JPG) for a mirror but I cannot find an equation that would allow me to relate reflectance to wavelength directly. I tried to find this in a couple of books but all I keep seeing are actual graphs and no explanation for how they created the graph

Thanks

Comment: What kind of mirror are we talking about? The graph looks like a calculated response for a dielectric mirror. There are physical models for the reflection and transmission on dielectric mirror. See e.g. http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/ewa/ch06.pdf for  an introduction of the most simple theoretical approach. The source mentions Matlab code that can do the calculations for you and you can buy commercial software that does this (and much more) based on either a description of the mirror's layers. That kind of software can usually also create a mirror from a required reflectance function.